# Оценка сложности криптографического алгоритма

Tags: криптография

Добрый день! Хочу выбрать самый сбалансированный криптографический алгоритм по соотношению безопасность-размер_устройства, для чего собираюсь построить ряд графических зависимостей, на основании которых буду думать дальше. Размер устройства буду измерять в GE(Gate Equivalent, 1GE - площадь занимаемая одним элементом NAND). А вот как оценить безопасность различных алгоритмов? На мой неискушенный взгляд самый простой способ - это откладывать на второй оси предполагаемое время взлома алгоритма брутфорсом, а потом сделать трехмерный график где по 3ей оси была бы сложность алгоритма. 
 Подскажите пожалуйста, какие методики расчета предполагаемого времени взлома будут оптимальны? Или может стоит просто считать за какое время n-битный счетчик примет все свои значения?

Comment: XOR с ключом, который по длине больше блока данных. Думаю, по соотношению цена-качество - вне конкуренции :-)

Comment: На счёт оченка сложности - у каждого алгоритма своя. Нужно поднимать документацию по каждому конкретному - и считать (или искать). Алгоритмы можно найти тут https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: Что вы называете сложностью алгоритма?

Comment: @Barmaley есть понятие "вычислительная сложность алгоритма". Часто считается через логарифм. [вики](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C), [хабр](http://habrahabr.ru/post/104219/) эта оценка позволяет выбрать извесный оцененый алгоритм из двух - прикинуть какой алгоритм для ПК легче, а какой сложнее.

Comment: Варианта два. Или перечисляем алгоритмы и напротив каждого рекомендуемого ставим "оценку". Или закрываем вопрос? Каким вы видите ответ на вопрос?

Comment: Да погодите закрывать еще. Просто не очень понятно, зачем вам вычислительная сложность. Она ведь применяется для оценки эффективности алгоритма скажем сортировки, оптимизации и проч. А какое он имеет отношение к криптографии? Причем тут его легкость для ПК?

Comment: Вот есть интересная статья https://habrahabr.ru/post/336578/

Comment: Найти вычислительную сложность для шифрования не удаётся. Можно только прикинуть сколько вложеных циклов внутри, и сколько кода внутри циклов.

Comment: @nick_n_a 
Давайте уточню контекст. Конечная цель всего этого - разработать методику аутентификации для IoT устройств и написать какой-то унифицированный протокол для этого.
Чтобы это сделать - нужно провести исследование, исходя из которого можно было бы определить, что лучше использовать.
Для этого нужно нарисовать толковые графики по которым можно будет, зная допустимую сложность микросхемы выбрать нужный шифр.
В данный момент я для начала хочу понять, по каким критериям лучше оценивать.
Cтатья с табличками:
https://cyberleninka.ru/article/v/legkovesnaya-kriptografiya-chast-1

Comment: @nick_n_a Один параметр для оценки алгоритма это GE, т.е. сложность микросхемы которая может реализовать такой алгоритм. Было бы круто хотя бы приблизительно знать кол-во аппаратных ресурсов требуемых для его взлома. Тогда можно было бы высчитать коэффициент.  У меня была идея взять статьи о уже состоявшихся взломах и пересчитать мощности которые они использовали в GE(принять 1GE = 4 транзистора), но похоже это тупиковый путь, т.к. нужно спрогнозировать взлом разных шифров, которые друг от друга отличаются структурно

Comment: @nick_n_a в качестве ответа мне вполне достаточно будет книги, статьи или методички с описанием чего-то подобного.
За статью на хабре спасибо, пригодится

Comment: Если бы мы могли наперед оценить предполагаемое время взлома, алгоритмов шифрования было бы в разы меньше. Но это невозможно сделать до того, как найдут атаки на алгоритм. Единственное на что остается смотреть, это размер ключа. Смотреть на лучшую атаку известную на данный момент бесполезно. Если есть алгоритм1 и алгоритм2 с ключами 256 бит. Для алгоритм1 известна атака за 2^254, для алгоритм2 известна атака за 2^253. Можем ли мы теперь считать, что алгоритм1 в 2 раза безопасней?